# TypeError: "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" error when using AWS signing Process for Python

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm validating my AWS keys for S3 storage for my Django project. So I'm following [the official walkthrough here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html). I've pasted the first part (`Using GET with an Authorization Header (Python)`) into my AWS `conf.py` file (which is imported into my `settings.py`). However the walkthrough is in Python 2.7 and my project is running off Python 3.5. Therefore I'm getting this error:

```
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256('').hexdigest()
```

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Any idea how I can fix this?

**EDIT** - Changing `payload_hash = hashlib.sha256('').hexdigest()` to `payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(''.encode()).hexdigest()` returns:

```
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope +\
                 '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request).hexdigest()
```

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

**EDIT2** - Canonical request

```
# Step 2: Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query 
# string (use '/' if no path)
canonical_uri = '/' 

# Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example (a GET request),
# request parameters are in the query string. Query string values must
# be URL-encoded (space=%20). The parameters must be sorted by name.
# For this example, the query string is pre-formatted in the request_parameters variable.
canonical_querystring = request_parameters

# Step 4: Create the canonical headers and signed headers. Header names
# must be trimmed and lowercase, and sorted in code point order from
# low to high. Note that there is a trailing \n.
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'

# Step 5: Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
# in the canonical_headers list, delimited with ";" and in alpha order.
# Note: The request can include any headers; canonical_headers and
# signed_headers lists those that you want to be included in the 
# hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'

# Step 6: Create payload hash (hash of the request body content). For GET
# requests, the payload is an empty string ("").
#payload_hash = hashlib.sha256('').hexdigest()
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(''.encode()).hexdigest()

# Step 7: Combine elements to create canonical request
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
```

Comment: You still did not encode the `canonical_request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call string's `encode` method before hashing:

```
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(''.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: @Zorgan can you add related code to the question? Did you encode `canonical_request` variable?

Comment: I've posted the code with the `canonical_request` in my edit. The full code is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Comment: Try `string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope +'\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode()).hexdigest()` instead of `string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope +\
                 '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request).hexdigest()`

Comment: When I change that I get this error: `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListObjects operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

Comment: My mistake I had a problem elsewhere - your method worked perfect. Thankyou.